# How to recover the residuals of glmer model

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial

I'm working on a logistic mixed model with `glmer` of the package `lme4` with `year` as a random effect (an intercept) in order to take the spatial autocorrelation(SAC). I want to test the SAC on the residual of the model by using Moran's I index but I cannot recover the serie of the residuals of the model. How to recover any type of residual from `glmer` classes to perform the spatial autocorrelation test?

Comment: See also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html

Answer (score 0):

All `merMod` objects have a `residuals()` method.

Say your fitted model object is called `mymod`, then it's `residuals(mymod)` to print residuals to the console.

To save the result to your dataframe it's

`mydata$mod1resid <- residuals(mymod)`